# Using universal * selector for border and font awesome and any other elements

Tags: css

For my borders, I just do this way,

```
* { 
  border:0 solid #color;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

then

```
.element {
  border-width:1px
}
```

When using font awesome,

```
*:before,*:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

then

```
.element:before {
 content:"\0000"
}
```

Is it ideal to use it this way?

Comment: Instead of *, why not just use a class so you aren't adding unnecessary CSS to everything? something like `.border { border: 0 solid #color; }` and `.fa:before, .fa:after { font-family: 'FontAwesome'; }` - then just add the class(es) to your HTML as you need

Comment: It's just I frequently use borders specially on the menu section. How about I do #container * { border:0 solid #color }... thanks for your advice.

Comment: If 80% or more of your code needs a defined border, and this keeps you from repeating the same code for a bunch of elements, I can see potentially using the * selector for it. Limiting it to a particular element on the page would be better than applying it to everything on the page. It's just sloppy for the sake of convenience.